# I have a question about std::vector<shared_ptr>

Tags: c++, class, c++11, shared-ptr, stdvector

I have a doubt about the structure of std::vector

If there are some class called foo.

I will write down some code for explanation.

```
class foo
{
  //do something...
};

void main(void)
{
  foo a;
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<foo>> foo_list;

  //Is it right? If not how can I do that?
  foo_list.push_back(a); 
}
```

Like this example, If the smart pointer was in vector, How can I put in original class in vector?

Comment: do you mean that a have to make heap pointer using make_shared?

Comment: If I have std::vector<std::shared_ptr> how can I put my class variable put in the vector?. It is my real question

Comment: If you don't know how to use a `shared_ptr`, then how do you know that you should do a vector of shared pointers instead of a vector of objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo_list` is a collection of `std::shared_ptr<foo>` (that is shared pointers to `foo` objects).

`foo_list.push_back(a)` is attempting to add a `foo` instance to `foo_list` - obviously this won't work because the types are different (one is a shared pointer the other isn't)

You need something like:

```
auto a = std::make_shared<foo>();
foo_list.push_back(a);
```